# jquery uncertain error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this code to access all the hidden elements from a form:

```
function get_hidden_val(ids,form_id)
{

    var get_check_val = document.getElementById(ids);
    if(get_check_val.checked){

    var div = $('<div></div>')
    .appendTo('form#bulk_add_cart')
    .attr('id',"bulk_"+form_id)

    $("form#" +form_id).find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){  
    var value =$(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var tags = "<input type='hidden' value='" + value + "' name='"+name+"'>";
    $('div#' +form_id).append(tags);
}); 
}
    else
    {
        $("form#bulk_add_cart").find('div#' +form_id).remove();
    }

}
```

My problem is when I click the first checkbox it give me the result but when i click the second checkbox it doesn't and also the another problem is when i click first checkbox it shows total hidden elements but when i second time checked it, it show 4 less ?

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly post your markup for a better response.

Comment: You have shown us nothing like an onclick handler. We are not psychic.

Comment: @karim79 its very big markup how can i attach it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  what r saying man ??

Comment: @rajesh: Don't attach it all. Post a minimal, complete testcase to jsfiddler.net that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal what is this jsfiddler.net, i am working on php

Comment: @rajesh: Then why is your question tagged "javascript" and "jquery", and why does it contain javascript code?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  dude it means that i dont know about javscript and jquery i am currently working on php

Comment: @rajesh: This question is about Javascript and jQuery. Where does PHP come into it? As for jsfiddle.net [sorry, I typo'd the URL before], why not go to the site and find out?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'ka ok thanks 4 the reply i got solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user704302: Missing `>`, update `var tags` to --

```
var tags = "<input type='hidden' value='" + value + "' id='"+id+"'>";
```

Comment: yaa thanks  stealthyninja for this help but this couldn't solve my problem

Comment: @rajesh: You need to post more of your code then, please. :-)

Comment: @rajesh: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to paste just the HTML and that specific JavaScript function which you've already posted on here. As soon as you click on _Save_ it'll create a unique URL for you which you can copy and paste from your address bar to here so that others may go and test/play with the code and suggest fixes and updates.